# Layout & cell issues when animating UICollectionView frame

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiviewanimation, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm facing a really weird issue with `UICollectionView`. I'm not very fond of some advanced collection view layout stuff but still, I consider this one a bit confusing.

[image: Collection view animated frame update glitch]

Applying a frame update (height change specifically) via animation makes the collection view (with red cells on the right) flush the about-to-dismiss cells immediately when setting the height to a lower value. Performing the same change on `UITableView` (with yellow cells on the left) works pretty fine. See this Playground example for a demonstration:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,
    UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    var col : UICollectionView?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = UITableViewCell()
        c.textLabel?.text = "cell"
        c.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        return c
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        c.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return c
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//      print(Thread.callStackSymbols.joined(separator: "\n") + "\n\n")
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        var f = view.bounds
        f.size.height = 300

        let holder = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
        holder.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth]

        f.size.width = 150
        f.size.height = view.frame.size.height

        let table = UITableView(frame: f, style: .plain)
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        table.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleRightMargin]

        f.origin.x = 150

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 50)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1

        let collection = UICollectionView(frame: f, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collection.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collection.delegate = self
        collection.dataSource = self
        collection.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleLeftMargin]
        col = collection

        view.addSubview(holder)
        holder.addSubview(table)
        holder.addSubview(collection)

        self.view = view
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        toggleContent()
    }

    func toggleContent()
    {
        guard let v = self.view.subviews.first else { return }

        var f = v.frame
        f.size.height = (f.size.height == 300) ? 150:300

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            v.frame = f
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1.5) {
            self.toggleContent()
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

I would expect it to work as a charm in the first place as the table view isn't affected by this issue.

I already tried using an overriden flow layout and:

- setting `shouldInvalidateLayout` methods to return `false` (tested as hitting when the cells are about to disappear) so I could deal with manual invalidation later
- extending a rect of `layoutAttributesForElements(in:)`
- overriding `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem`

None of it having any impact. The commented out `print()` in `collectionView(_:didEndDisplaying:)` shows the `layoutSubviews` with cells dismissal is called anyway.

Motivation: here's the real-world issue caused by this:

[image: Real-world problem]

I guess there might be a very easy, proper solution to this? I'd prefer it over anything “extremely hacky”.

Please let's stick with fixing the Playground example without guessing! ;)

Comment: As I understand, problem is because you changed height of container view while animating. To resolve problem, I suggest to update height after end drag

Comment: That would be a workaround only. In case of need, the UI may rely on auto-layout or autoresizing mask, both of these being potentially broken by doing this. Moreover, if I disable autoresizing mask and apply collection view height change after container height update, I'd have the same issue the other way round, when increasing the height.

Comment: I handled this by changing the height after the drag down was complete and the user could not see this going on. I stopped changing the height during the drag if that makes sense. Interesting that a tableview does not do this.

Comment: Your test project does not really matter in terms of the interaction because if you wait until it is fully animated down to change the height and change it immediately on dragging up the reload will never be seen by the user as the origin is all that would need changed.

Comment: The test example is only a tear-down demonstration of the layout issue when changing collection view bounds. I know how to work around the issue in my case and I already addressed it, what I'm asking here is A) a proper solution (in case I'm doing the animated frame update wrong) or B) a confirmation this is an iOS issue I can submit (which I probably will).

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your views while animating by adding `layoutIfNeeded()` inside your animation block like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
    v.frame = f
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

and see if it works :/

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Tried that as well, forgot to mention. This only “improves” the experience by animating the newly added cells when increasing the size, but decreasing still produces an instant cells removal. As I mentioned, `layoutSubviews` is called on the collection view as soon as the animation is fired, causing the cells to be dropped.

Comment: works for me, but could someone explain why it works?